# How to get clauses of the DNF/CNF expression in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, boolean-logic

According to sympy docs on [logic package](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html), we can transform an arbitrary boolean expression into DNF/CNF form, using `to_cnf`/`to_dnf` or `simplify_logic(expr, form='cnf'/'dnf')`.

*But after that, how to get the clauses from the result?*

We can try using the `args` field. BUT using it is very inconvenient. E.g., if you transform a simple expression like `~a` into CNF/DNF, then you get `~a` as the result, and then calling `(~a).args` returns `()`, which is not the clause sought! (of course, I can workaround with `if` checks, but that is ugly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find the native method in sympy, but I was wrong when wrote that using `args` is ugly. Here is the solution.

```
def clauses(expr) -> tuple:    # for DNFs only
    if not isinstance(expr, sympy.logic.boolalg.Or):
        return expr,
    return expr.args
```

Notre that the function returns `(true,)`/`(false,)` for true/false values. For CNFs, change to `isinstance(expr, And)`.